# Use Cargo with a custom linker

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I would like to use `cargo` to build projects requiring a custom compilation (calling the assembler, the linker, …).

I was able to do this with a build script, but it is not perfect. For instance, to build the code from this [tutorial](http://blog.theincredibleholk.org/blog/2013/11/18/booting-to-rust/), I made the following build script:

```
use std::fs::create_dir;
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    build();
    link();
    iso();
}

fn build() {
    Command::new("cargo")
        .current_dir("uefi_app")
        .args(&["rustc", "--", "--emit", "obj"])
        .status().unwrap();
}

fn iso() {
    let disk_file = "target/debug/disk.img";
    let disk_dir = "target/debug/disk";
    let efi_boot = disk_dir.to_owned() + "/efi/boot";
    let copy_dest = efi_boot.clone() + "/bootx64.efi";

    let dd_of = "of=".to_owned() + disk_file;
    Command::new("dd")
        .args(&["if=/dev/zero", &dd_of, "bs=512", "count=93750"])
        .status().unwrap();

    Command::new("parted")
        .args(&[disk_file, "-s", "-a", "minimal", "mklabel", "gpt"])
        .status().unwrap();

    Command::new("parted")
        .args(&[disk_file, "-s", "-a", "minimal", "mkpart", "EFI", "FAT16", "2048s", "93716s"])
        .status().unwrap();

    Command::new("parted")
        .args(&[disk_file, "-s", "-a", "minimal", "toggle", "1", "boot"])
        .status().unwrap();

    Command::new("sudo")
        .args(&["losetup", "--offset", "1048576", "--sizelimit", "46934528", "/dev/loop0", disk_file])
        .status().unwrap();

    let _ = create_dir(disk_dir);

    Command::new("sudo")
        .args(&["mkdosfs", "-F", "32", "/dev/loop0"])
        .status().unwrap();

    Command::new("sudo")
        .args(&["mount", "/dev/loop0", disk_dir])
        .status().unwrap();

    Command::new("sudo")
        .args(&["mkdir", "-p", &efi_boot])
        .status().unwrap();

    Command::new("sudo")
        .args(&["cp", "target/debug/boot.efi", &copy_dest])
        .status().unwrap();

    Command::new("sudo")
        .args(&["umount", disk_dir])
        .status().unwrap();

    Command::new("sudo")
        .args(&["losetup", "-d", "/dev/loop0"])
        .status().unwrap();

    Command::new("sudo")
        .args(&["rm", "-R", disk_dir])
        .status().unwrap();
}

fn link() {
    Command::new("x86_64-efi-pe-ld")
        .args(&["--oformat", "pei-x86-64", "--subsystem", "10", "-pie", "-e", "efi_main", "uefi_app/target/debug/uefi_app.o", "-o", "target/debug/boot.efi"]).output().unwrap();
}
```

You can see the complete crate [here](https://github.com/antoyo/uefi_rust).

Another example is [this crate](https://github.com/antoyo/os_in_rust) for the OS tutorials from [here](http://os.phil-opp.com/).

This require a separate crate because running cargo in a build script seems to trigger an infinite loop.

The issue with this build script is that I need to run `cargo clean` everytime I update the code of the crate compiled by the build script.

How could I use cargo to automate such a compilation?

What I want is just typing `cargo run` and get an ISO (or harddrive file) and launch the VM.

Comment: Your title says "custom linker" but the question seems to be asking about completely implementing a build system like Make. You may want to try to sync these two things up. Additionally, this isn't really what [build scripts are for](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html), which probably explains the recursive issue.

Comment: @Sephmaster Would it be at better question if I only ask to use another linker?

Answer (score 8):

You can specify a custom linker in the .cargo/config file. [See this](https://github.com/hackndev/zinc/blob/master/.cargo/config) as an example:

```
[target.thumbv7em-none-eabi]
linker = "arm-none-eabi-gcc"
ar = "arm-none-eabi-ar"
```

Comment: Where should I put this config file?

Comment: IIRC the .cargo directory goes in the root of your project. i.e the same directory as your Cargo.toml file. The config file goes in the .cargo directory.

Comment: how to specify linker for all types  of targets?

Comment: This page explains the config hierarchy and the multiple places you can put that, depending if you want to affect a module, project, all projects etc.
https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `--config` to specify the linker path, if you don't want to use a config file. See [cargo configuration](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#command-line-overrides).

For your example this should work:

`cargo build --target thumbv7em-none-eabi --config target.thumbv7em-none-eabi.linker=\"arm-none-eabi-gcc\"`

Comment: BTW: The backslash escaped double quotes are important.